# Rails+PostgreSQL: search_path depending on subdomain

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, connection-pooling

In our rails 2.x application the `search_path` of the database connection depends on the subdomain through which the application is contacted (basically `search_path = "production_"+subdomain`). Because the `search_path` is defined per connection and database connections are shared over requests, even concurrently, this is a problem. I would rather not change concurrency to only serve one request at a time for obvious reasons.

So is there a way to group the database connections in the connection pool and set some kind of policy that only a fitting connection is used for the request? Or is there a way to use one connection pool per subdomain (where the pools are automatically discarded after a timeout)? Starting a rails instance for each subdomain is no option because there might be many idling subdomains (it's some kind of pro-account where you get a subdomain and your own "world" that differs from the rest of the site in some tables).

What would be the best solution for this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just set connection.search_path at the beginning of the request, before any objects are loaded, and you'll be fine. In our case we have a Rack app that wraps our rails app and does this setup for us based on the incoming domain.